# Redirecting 404 pages to another active pages in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, redirects, 301-redirect

I have one product page indexed on Google but that link does not exist anymore and hits 404 page.

What I want to do is to redirect that link in .htaccess to another product page since it ranks very high. So I tryed almost every option and combination i.e.

```
Redirect 301 /old-page.html /new-page.html

Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/old-page.html   http://www.example.com/new-page.html
```

etc. but none of those works for me.

Could anyone help me, is there any other solution or practice how to redirect thispage to another.

Btw. my links path contain 2 subfolders each like:

```
http://www.example.com/subfolder1/subfolder2/product.html
```

Comment: Are you editing the `.htaccess` file in the document root of your site? Do you have other directives in your `.htaccess` file? If so, please include your entire `.htaccess` file in your question. Do you have any other `.htaccess` files in subdirectories? "my links path contain 2 subfolders" - Although neither of your example directives include this?

Comment: Thx. for respond @MrWhite ... this is my htaccess file https://www.codepile.net/pile/rB585mzm    yes i am editing htaccess file in root. i do have other htaccess file in my subdirectories, dont know how many... but i do not have htaccess file in subfolder of pages i want to redirect. actually those are nonexisting subfolders since URL is generated dynamically

Comment: I can't see where you have placed these directives in your `.htaccess` file (in your code dump at codepile.net)? codepile.net also seems to have parsed the file in some way and appears to be _hiding_ part directives (perhaps because it has been formatted as HTML)? The "raw" option on that site is not working. Please add the code to your question, rather than link to an external site.

Comment: sorry @MrWhite ... i just added a code to my question

Comment: What version of Apache server is running for your site?  `Redirect 301 /old-page.html /new-page.html` should work for version 2.4 but not for version 2.2.  `Redirect 301 http://www.example.com/old-page.html   http://www.example.com/new-page.html` isn't valid syntax for any version of Apache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the exact URL you are trying to redirect it's difficult to say whether you were experiencing a conflict with your existing directives or not. Although, if you were still seeing a 404 then your first directive:

> ```
> Redirect 301 /old-page.html /new-page.html
> ```

...should have still "worked" (providing you are on Apache 2.2.6+)

However, since you already have a lot of existing mod_rewrite directives, you should really be using a mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` for this redirect, instead of a mod_alias `Redirect`. The reason being that mod_rewrite executes *before* mod_alias, regardless of the order of directives in `.htaccess`, so you can get unexpected conflicts (you already have many mod_rewrite *redirects*) or at the very least unnecessary additional processing before the redirect.

Try something like the following at the very top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteRule ^subfolder/old-page\.html$ https://www.example.com/subfolder/new-page.html [R=302,L]
```

Note there is no slash prefix on the `RewriteRule` *pattern*. I've included `https` and the full URL in the *substitution* since you do have a HTTP to HTTPS redirect later in the file.

I would add, however, that your directives do seem a bit *muddled* in that you have rewrites before redirects and your canonical non-www to www and HTTP to HTTPS redirects are at the very end so may get skipped entirely.

Comment: thank you @MrWhite. the second solution worked  by me perfectly.